# Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature:

Tags: scheduled-apex, callout, future

I'm working on a schedulable class that makes and http callout, I need my schedulable method to start my @future method with my callout. The error I'm getting is

> " Method does not exist or incorrect signature: returnAuth()"

```
 global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    returnAuth();
 }
 @future(callout = true)
  static void returnAuth(string loginstring, string Idstring) {
    string xAuthToken;
    string st_Today;
    If(loginstring != null) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setMethod('POST'); // Method Type

        req.setEndpoint('web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/login'); //salestree url

        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('{ "username" : ', loginstring);


        res = http.send(req);
```

Anyone know how i can make this work?

Comment: The `returnAuth` takes two arguments loginString and IdString. Provide those two arguments in `returnAuth` method to remove this error.

Comment: @Ashwani Can you post that as an answer rather than a comment. Then the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: n.b. `global` modifier is not required unless doing managed package; `public` will suffice

Comment: What is the line code which is causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

The `returnAuth` takes two arguments `loginString` and `IdString`.

Provide those two arguments in `returnAuth` method to remove this error. This would resolve the problem.